# C++ How to make a GUI in directx?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, visual-c++, directx

I have few questions on this Subjects.
I created a class for buttons, the class has problem.
Problem is:
1.  I wanna create function to be called if button is clicked, the problem is that every single button gonna do different thing if it was clicked.  So i don't know how i can create function that will do different thing for every button.
I have no idea how i should design my interface.
If you can give me an idea on how i should design my GUI that would be great.
This is my button class

```
class GUIButtons
{
public:
    GUIButtons(void);
    ~GUIButtons(void);
    void LoadMesh(string fileName, int startAnimation, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev);
    void Render(float timeElapsed, D3DXMATRIX *matWorld);
    void EventProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev);
    void Picking(HWND hWnd, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev);
private:
    CXFileEntity *Button;
};
```

**EDIT 2:**
Guys is this possible?
I create two functions and than ill point one function to another.
Something like this

```
void a()
{
     ....
}
void b() = a;
```

**EDIT 3:**
Ok should i use this way for the `onClick()` function.

```
void Onclick( void(*fun) )
{
    fun();
}
```

i pass a function to `OnClick` than it calls the function.
should i use this way?

Comment: If you're already on a Microsoft platform, why not use Windows Presentation Foundation?

Comment: Because,  in directx full screen you can't use Windows Presentation Foundation

Comment: What you wrote as your 2nd edit is not possible. But you can use function pointers. But seriously, using classes/polymorphism is better, safer and more elegant, and you'll learn more by doing it that way :)

Comment: You can use Boost Signals library to achieve something similar to what you want. Check it out at: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/signals.html or the one that is threading friendly at: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/signals2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use inheritance/polymorphism: The base class is `GUIButtons`, and every new individual button derives from that base clase:

```
class MyButton : public GUIButtons { ... }
```

And then the functionality for a click comes in a virtual method `onClick()` or whatever.

More detail:

```
class GUIButtons 
{
   ... \\ lots of stuff
   virtual void onClick() { };
};

class CloseButton : public GUIButtons
{
  ...
  virtual void onClick()
  {
    //code to close window
  }
};

class SettingsButton : public GUIButtons
{
  ...
  virtual void onClick()
  {
    //stuff to open settings menu
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm confused.. So let say that I created two buttons.  If first button is clicked the window should close, if the second button is clicked messagebox should show up.  How am i suppose to do that with one function?

Comment: I edited my answer. As a very simple alternative (altough not as powerful) you can have an enum variable for the button action ( CLOSE, MESSAGE, NEW_GAME, ... ) and then use a switch-statement in the function that's called when the button was clicked.

Comment: Having a definition for OnClick() for every scenario is not the job of the GUI library. The library has to provide an interface so that the application that uses the widgets can handle it however it wants it to.

Comment: Sure. That's why I favor the version that uses polymorphism. But if you don't write a GUI _library_ but only a simple window with 3 buttons, why not take the simple approach?

Comment: If its going to be a simple window with 3 buttons then using inheritance will do. But keeping them decoupled from the widget is lot more scalable.

Comment: I'm not just creating 3 buttons and I'm not creating a function for every button

Answer (score 1):

Button click is an action/event. You can encapsulate the click action as a class. This action is interpreted and used differently by the application that uses the button widget. The gui library has to notify that a button has been clicked with the relevant information. You can refer to popular GUI libraries like Qt or Gtk+ as examples to know how they implement GUI events and much more.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you the book ["DirectX 9 User Interfaces: Design and Implementation"](http://www.ebookcomputer.com/screen/cover3/1453438893.jpg). I have it and i may say that you'll find there everything what you need!!!;)